# WPF hide a row, but empty space doesn't sweep out

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf window with a grid. I would like to hide rows and I do with this code as shown in other stackoverflow threads:

```
            buttonsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; or buttonsGrid.Height = 0;
            dayTimePicker.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; or dayTimePicker.Height = 0;
```

Set Visibility to Collapsed or Height to 0 gives the same effect, but I would like the white space occupied by these Rows to sweep ... I would like the whole window to be occupied by the indexed row 0. .. How can I do it?

This is my window:

```
<Window x:Class="PerformanceVideoRec.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    xmlns:DTControl="clr-namespace:DayTimePickControl"
    Title="{StaticResource ID_TITLE}" Height="600" Width="900" Loaded="Window_Loaded"> <!--Closing="Window_Closing"> -->

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ControlPart" IsEnabled="False">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LeftGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Background="Gray">
                <wf:PictureBox x:Name="playWindow"></wf:PictureBox>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
            <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1">
                <Button x:Name="btnShowHideControls" Content="Nascondi Controlli" Click="btnShowHideControls_Click"/>
            </UniformGrid>
            <UniformGrid Columns="6" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="buttonsGrid">
                <Button x:Name="btnPause" Margin="5" Width="50" Content="{StaticResource ID_PAUSE}" Click="btnPause_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Margin="5" Width="50" Content="{StaticResource ID_PLAY}" Click="btnPlay_Click"  Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnStop" Margin="5" Width="50" Content="{StaticResource ID_STOP}" Click="btnStop_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnSlow" Margin="5" Width="50" Content="{StaticResource ID_SLOW}" Click="btnSlow_Click"></Button>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbSpeed" IsEnabled="False" Width="50" Height="25" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1X" />
                <Button x:Name="btnFast" Margin="5" Width="50" Content="{StaticResource ID_FAST}" Click="btnFast_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnNormal" Margin="5" Width="50" Content="{StaticResource ID_NORMAL}" Click="btnNormal_Click"></Button>
            </UniformGrid>
            <DTControl:DayTimePick x:Name="dayTimePicker" Grid.Row="3" Width="550" Height="100" Grid.RowSpan="2" OnTimeClick="dayTimePicker_OnTimeClick"></DTControl:DayTimePick>
        </Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="PlayBackFrame" Grid.Column="1" Background="AliceBlue" ></Frame>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It is not good practice to set Height to 0 when you want to collpapse a control.

Answer (score 2):

The MVVM way:

- make a separate view model for the part of UI you want to collapse. Let's call it PlayViewModel,
- make a DataTemplate for it,
- expose it as a property (e.g. let's call it Play, don't forget to raise property change event) in the view model which is a DataContext for the whole view
- you display it in your grid with ContentPresenter, ContentPresenter.Content bound to Play property
- you do hiding by null-ing Play property, you show it by restoring it.

You get testability for free.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and bind the the property `Visibility` of the control inside the row you want to collapse with a converter.

I usually use the NuGet package [Mvvm Light](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs/), [documentation](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/documentation) to have some facilities while using Data Binding. (In this case `RelayCommand`, `RaisePropertyChanged` implementation)

A very basic example:

Part of the view. Here you can notice the Binding between the `Visibility` property of the button and the property `IsButton1Visible` of the `ViewModel`. Of course `bool` and `Visibility` aren't the same type, so I had to create a mapping using an `IValueConverter`:

```
 <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="1" Visibility="{Binding IsButton1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="2" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="3" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="4" />
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Toggle button 1 visibility" Command="{Binding ToggleButton1Visibility}" />

</Grid>
```

The window's constructor in the code behind (you could also bind the `ViewModel` via the `DataContext` property directly into the `View`), used to associate the `View` with the `ViewModel`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MyWindowViewModel();
}
```

The converter to convert `true` to `Visibility.Visible`:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

`App.xaml`, `Application.Resource` part, used to make the `View` "see" the converter:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

</Application.Resources>
```

The ViewModel. Here `RaisePropertyChanged` of `set` method of `IsButton1Visible` is very important because it notifies the `View` that the property is changed, so that the `View` can refresh itself:

```
public class MyWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isButton1Visibile = true;
    public bool IsButton1Visible
    {
        get => _isButton1Visibile;
        set
        {
            if (_isButton1Visibile == value)
                return;

            _isButton1Visibile = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsButton1Visible));
        }
    }


    RelayCommand _toggleButton1Visbility;
    public RelayCommand ToggleButton1Visibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _toggleButton1Visbility ?? (_toggleButton1Visbility = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    IsButton1Visible = !IsButton1Visible;
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LeftGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(0);
LeftGrid.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(0);
```

If you want to restore make this

```
   LeftGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);
    LeftGrid.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Comment: If I do it in this way, I lost the original Height values (55, 5, 5 and 20). How can I set it ?

Comment: Works good thank you! But.. How can I restore the "5*" and "20*" original values?

Comment: Just set hights to this : new GridLength(55, GridUnitType.Star); new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);

Comment: Sorry, I fix by myself:

LeftGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);
LeftGrid.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star

Comment: Is it possible to hide also the "PlayBackFrame"?

Comment: Yes your answer is great!  Is it possible to hide also the "PlayBackFrame"?

Comment: ControlPart.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(0); its all